# Standardizing the casting of list values in java

Tags: java

I have a `List<Node>` of JCR nodes which I need to cast to different models. At the moment, each one of the models have a separate function:

```
public List<MetaModel> castNodesToMetaModel(List<Node> nodes) {
    List<MetaModel> models = new ArrayList<MetaModel>();
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        models.add(new MetaModel(node, this));
    }
    return models;
}
protected List<ArticleModel> castNodesToArticleModel(List<Node> nodes) {
    List<ArticleModel> models = new ArrayList<ArticleModel>();
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        models.add(new ArticleModel(node, this));
    }
    return models;
}
```

Is there a way that I can standardise this casting using the `T` type?

```
protected <T> List<T> castNodes(T className, List<Node> nodes) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (Node node : nodes) {
        list.add(new T(node, this)); // Cannot do: new T()
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but the signature needs to be slightly different.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

protected <T> List<T> castNodes(Class<T> clazz, List<Node>) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
        Constructor c = clazz.getConstructor(Node.class, getClass());        
        for (Node node : nodes)
            list.add((T) c.newInstance(node, this));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle
    }
    return list;
}
```

You shouldn't really catch a general `Exception` (you should catch more specific types), but this gives you the idea.

Comment: Is Constructor an instance of java.lang.reflect.Constructor ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I should have added the relevant imports.

Comment: @bashaus Yes it is

Comment: You may have issues with accessibility. `c.setAccessible(true)` may be required.

Comment: @bashaus It's also possible that you shouldn't pass `getClass()`, but instead pass some `SpecificClass.class`. As soon as you start using reflection, you bypass a lot of the usual checks, so it's very difficult to get this kind of thing right.

Answer (score 2):

Use Java 8 approach:

```
public static <T> List<T> mapNodes(List<Node> nodes, Function<Node, T> mapFunction) {
        return nodes.stream().map(mapFunction).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The call it like this:

```
List<MetaModel> metaModels = mapNodes(nodeList, node -> new MetaModel(node, this));

List<ArticleModel> articleModels = mapNodes(nodeList, node -> new ArticleModel(node, this));
```

**** EDIT ****

If you're stuck with java 7 I would suggest a good Object Oriented approach instead of reflection. Such as this:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertNodes(List<Node> nodes, NodeConverter<T> converter) {
    ArrayList<T> newNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        newNodes.add(converter.convert(node));
    }
    return newNodes;
}

private static interface NodeConverter<T> {

    public T convert(Node node);
}
public static class NodeConverterFactory {

    public static final NodeConverter<MetaModel> metaModel(final Object thiz) {
        return new NodeConverter<MetaModel>() {
            @Override
            public MetaModel convert(Node node) {
                return new MetaModel(node, thiz);
            }
        };
    }
    public static final NodeConverter<ArticleModel> articleModel(final Object thiz) {
        return new NodeConverter<ArticleModel>() {
            @Override
            public ArticleModel convert(Node node) {
                return new ArticleModel(node, thiz);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

That then you use like this:

```
List<MetaModel> metaModels = convertNodes(nodeList, NodeConverterFactory.metaModel(this));

List<ArticleModel> articleModels = convertNodes(nodeList, NodeConverterFactory.articleModel(this));
```

While more verbose than the reflection approach, it's clearer, more flexible (since you can implement all kinds of converters and not be stuck with one kind of constructor) and type safe. The reflection approach could lead you to runtime problems if the constructor/method used doesn't exist.

Comment: I like this approach, but I think we're stuck with Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the [`Class.new instance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) method of the `Class` object you pass to the method via the parameter `className`.